# Unable to filter a data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using something like this to filter my data frame:

```
d1 = data.frame(data[data$ColA == "ColACat1" & data$ColB == "ColBCat2", ])
```

When I print `d1`, it works as expected. However, when I type d1$ColB, it still prints everything from the original data frame.

```
> print(d1)
ColA     ColB
-----------------
ColACat1 ColBCat2
ColACat1 ColBCat2

> print(d1$ColA)
Levels: ColACat1 ColACat2
```

Maybe this is expected but when I pass `d1` to ggplot, it messes up my graph and does not use the filter. Is there anyway I can filter the data frame and get **only** the records that match the filter? I want `d1` to not know the existence of `data`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you allude to, the default behavior in R is to treat character columns in data frames as a special data type, called a `factor`. This is a feature, not a bug, but like any useful feature if you're not expecting it and don't know how to properly use it, it can be quite confusing.

`factors` are meant to represent categorical (rather than numerical, or quantitative) variables, which comes up often in statistics.

The subsetting operations you used do in fact work normally. Namely, they will return the correct subset of your data frame. However, the `levels` attribute of that variable remains unchanged, and still has *all* the original levels in it.

This means that any method written in R that is designed to take advantage of `factors` will treat that column as a categorical variable with a bunch of levels, many of which just aren't present. In statistics, one often wants to track the presence of 'missing' levels of categorical variables.

I actually also prefer to work with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, but many people frown on that since it can reduce code portability. (`TRUE` is the default, so sharing your code with someone else may be risky unless you preface every single script with a call to `options`).

A potentially more convenient solution, particularly for data frames, is to combine the `subset` and `droplevels` functions:

```
subsetDrop <- function(...){
    droplevels(subset(...))
}
```

and use this function to extract subsets of your data frames in a way that is assured to remove any unused levels in the result.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for the explanation. What I did not understand was why ggplot ended up using levels that did not exist. May be they had their own reasons. I am a complete beginner in both R and ggplot so I ended up spending more than an hour trying to understand what happened :)

Comment: That treatment of factor levels (i.e. keeping them despite a lack of data), for instance when faceting, is considered 'normal' in the stats world, but it flummoxes most everyone else. The rationale is that if something is missing, you want to explicitly _show_ that its missing, e.g. by displaying a facet with no data in it.

Answer (score 2):

This was such a pain! ggplot messes up if you don't do this right. Using this option at the beginning of my script solved it:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Looks like it is the intended behavior but unfortunately I had turned this feature on for some other purpose and it started causing trouble for all my other scripts.

Comment: This will solve your problem, but the default global setting is stringsAsFactors=TRUE. You can also pass this as an argument when you construct the data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE). But in your example that would have to have been done when you constructed the initial 'data' data.frame.